# {Spring boot + Hibernate + MySQL} not able to obtain DB connection

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've read many post in order to find a solution. I would like to ask for help finding the problem. Below is the application.properties configuration file and the output with the error messages.

**aplication.properties:**

```
# DATASOURCE
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb
spring.datasource.name=hibernatedb
spring.datasource.username=nunit 
spring.datasource.password=nunit
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# CONTAINER
server.port=8080
server.context-path=/nunit/api

# JPA
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# JDBC.X
db.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306;databaseName=hibernatedb
db.user=nunit
db.pass=nunit

# HIBERNATE.X
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.

# SECURITY
security.basic.enabled=true

# HTTP REQUEST
spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true

# CORS configuration 
endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=*
endpoints.cors.allowed-headers=*
endpoints.cors.allowed-methods=*
endpoints.cors.mapping=/**

#JACKSON
spring.jackson.date-format=MM/dd/yyyy
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

**Console output:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.5.RELEASE)

2016-08-13 19:30:19.656  INFO 3868 --- [           main] com.nunit.NUnitServices                  : Starting NUnitServices on iNViNCiBLe with PID 3868 (C:\Users\nUnit\workspace_neon\nUnitServices\target\classes started by nUnit in C:\Users\nUnit\workspace_neon\nUnitServices)
2016-08-13 19:30:19.656  INFO 3868 --- [           main] com.nunit.NUnitServices                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-13 19:30:19.794  INFO 3868 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@140e5a13: startup date [Sat Aug 13 19:30:19 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-13 19:30:23.766  INFO 3868 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$673436dd] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-13 19:30:25.120  INFO 3868 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-08-13 19:30:25.162  INFO 3868 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-08-13 19:30:25.165  INFO 3868 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
2016-08-13 19:30:25.482  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/nunit/api]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-08-13 19:30:25.483  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5689 ms
2016-08-13 19:30:26.626  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-13 19:30:26.627  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-13 19:30:26.628  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-13 19:30:26.628  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-13 19:30:26.632  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] .e.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2016-08-13 19:30:26.632  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-08-13 19:30:27.367  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] b.a.s.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration : 

Using default security password: f5fc04b8-ea2e-4a37-b3c2-8cc4b439ea9b

2016-08-13 19:30:27.491  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/css/**'], []
2016-08-13 19:30:27.491  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/js/**'], []
2016-08-13 19:30:27.492  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/images/**'], []
2016-08-13 19:30:27.492  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], []
2016-08-13 19:30:27.492  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/error'], []
2016-08-13 19:30:27.653  INFO 3868 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$ApplicationNoWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$1@6a07267e, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@31e38a81, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@489f333f, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@47e64ac4, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@59f36eca, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@716af3b4, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@71a82ef, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3131177c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1732285a, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@615c6f88, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1a4e3459]
2016-08-13 19:30:28.258  INFO 3868 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-08-13 19:30:28.289  INFO 3868 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-08-13 19:30:28.455  INFO 3868 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-08-13 19:30:28.458  INFO 3868 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-08-13 19:30:28.461  INFO 3868 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-08-13 19:30:28.871  INFO 3868 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-08-13 19:30:29.631 ERROR 3868 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'nunit '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4323) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1267) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    42 more ...

2016-08-13 19:30:29.636  WARN 3868 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'nunit '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2016-08-13 19:30:29.656  INFO 3868 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2016-08-13 19:30:29.680  INFO 3868 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder    : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2016-08-13 19:30:30.237  INFO 3868 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-08-13 19:30:30.500  INFO 3868 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-08-13 19:30:30.500  INFO 3868 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2016-08-13 19:30:30.500 ERROR 3868 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'nunit '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4323) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1267) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    41 more ...

2016-08-13 19:30:30.516 ERROR 3868 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000319: Could not get database metadata

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'nunit '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4323) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1267) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    43 more ...

2016-08-13 19:30:30.516 ERROR 3868 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000299: Could not complete schema update

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'nunit '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4323) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1267) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    43 more ...

2016-08-13 19:30:31.055  INFO 3868 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@140e5a13: startup date [Sat Aug 13 19:30:19 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-13 19:30:31.288  INFO 3868 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/services/helloWorld],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.util.List<com.nunit.rest.Message> com.nunit.rest.ServiceController.postHelloWorldMessage()
2016-08-13 19:30:31.291  INFO 3868 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/services/helloWorld]}" onto public java.util.List<com.nunit.rest.Message> com.nunit.rest.ServiceController.getHelloWorldMessage()
2016-08-13 19:30:31.297  INFO 3868 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-08-13 19:30:31.298  INFO 3868 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-08-13 19:30:31.381  INFO 3868 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-13 19:30:31.382  INFO 3868 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-13 19:30:31.506  INFO 3868 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-13 19:30:32.129  INFO 3868 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-08-13 19:30:32.339  INFO 3868 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-08-13 19:30:32.352  INFO 3868 --- [           main] com.nunit.NUnitServices                  : Started NUnitServices in 13.541 seconds (JVM running for 14.527)
```

Comment: You mean `Access denied for user 'nunit '@'localhost' (using password: YES)` ? Standard MySQL error message saying that you do not have permission to that database using that user.

Comment: have you tried to connect to the same database using the same credentials with the `mysql` command line client?

Comment: @Neil Stockton, dschulz: Yes, I did verified that the user has permissions to connect to the DB using the MySQL console and command prompt as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I've read this post [here](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/06/spring-boot-data-access-with-jpa-hibernate-and-mysql/), I was able to resolve the issue after adding this property `entitymanager.packagesToScan` and the proper package to scan.

Comment: I see you have been looking to that tuto to write your code. After having a look to the link, I can tell you that: 1. It creates a configuration class to configure Hibernate and JPA. That would be the way to go in plain Spring, Spring boot does that for you instead, you only need to specify the properties to use in your application.properties. 2. The repository is implemented as a class, while the way to go with Spring boot and Spring Data JPA is to write an interface and let Spring implement it using a proxy. So this tutorial is simply an overkill if you're in Spring Boot.

Comment: See how it's done in the official docs: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ No `@Configuration` class is required.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker: I'm using interfaces for Repositories, the only thing this tutorial did helped me was to point to the config class for the DB.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker: OK, I'll check it.

Comment: The config class for the DB is just unecessary in boot. You can get rid of it, it's something that the framework already provides for you. Just do it with the properties Spring defines by default (`spring.X`), as it's stated in my answer. To see the whole range of properties available for boot, have a look to this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: @Xtreme Biker: Yes, I've already checked it but it states for common properties not whole range.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're writting so many configuration lines, this should be enough to connect to your database . No need to tell Hibernate to use MySql dialect neither to configure Hibernate and JDBC yourself:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=nunit
spring.datasource.password=nunit
```

Then you can try enabling the rest of the settings like SQL logs, database initialization and so on:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```